# Why there's usage of similar words in a sentence in typical novels?

Tags: word-usage

For example in a novel I'm currently reading, one character is being described as being"cunning" and"sly" in one sentence as ,"She was beautiful, she was cunning and sly, she had a charm no woman could match."  Is it to put emphasis on this specific trait of the character or something else?

The excerpt is from a novel "The feast of roses" by Indu Sundaresan.

Comment: Because **cunning** and **sly** do not have exactly the same meaning. You can be **sly** without being manipulative, for example.

Comment: As @Weather Vane says, these synonyms do not overlap totally. Some might consider that they overlap sufficiently to see their use together as tautological, while others would consider that the flow of the sentence is better as it stands, and accept the slight semantic awkwardness. But not all novelists are paragons of superb literature.

Comment: Partially it's done for emphasis.